# TypeError: firebase.messaging is not a function in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

While trying to fetch the FCM messages in node.js using firebase module, following error "TypeError: firebase.messaging is not a function" is occurring.

```
var firebase = require("firebase");

firebase.initializeApp({
    apiKey: "xxxxxxx",
    authDomain: "xxxxxxx",
    databaseURL: "xxxxxxx",
    projectId: "xxxxxxx",
    storageBucket: "xxxxxxx",
    messagingSenderId: "xxxxxxx"
});

const messaging = firebase.messaging();
```

How to rectify this error and how to use firebase module to pull messages??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The criteria you are trying to use only works on the browser:

You have to require `firebase-messaging`, check this full sample it will guide you https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-js/tree/master/messaging

For nodeJS implementation, you have to use `admin.messaging`

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.messaging

```
// Get the Messaging service for the default app
var defaultMessaging = admin.messaging();
```

Comment: My idea is to create node app which will receive notification from fcm without any browser interaction. I was trying these methods `var firebase = require("firebase/messaging");` which is not working.

Answer (score 22):

You must included `import '@firebase/messaging'` for it to work.
So it's supposed to look like this:

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';
import '@firebase/messaging';
```

Answer (score 3):

The documentation for Firebase does not make it clear that there is a difference of features available based on the current environment. `firebase.messaging` is not available to a Node.js client, but is available from the `firebase-admin` package. However, this package alone comes with a different set of features specfically for `firebase.messaging`.

You can see what's available to you based on your environment in the Firebase Reference docs. Specifically for your case the [Node.js (Client)](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/node/) section.

Answer (score 0):

### For `react-native-firebase version 5.x.x and 6.x.x`

```js
import firebase from '@react-native-firebase/app'
import '@react-native-firebase/messaging'
```

for example `get token`

```js
const fcmToken = await firebase.messaging().getToken();
console.log(fcmToken)
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case was that I was importing firebase only as

```
import '@firebase/app'
```

instead of

```
import * as firebase from '@firebase/app'
```

after formatting it, I was able to access messaging from firebase.firebase.messaging()