# Firebase React Native -- how to grab and transmit Device ID/Token?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native

First time Firebase and RN user here, trying to figure out how to transmit the Device ID/Token of the app user.

I'm using something basic like this to transmit information to my firebase database right now (using `firebase.database().ref()`).

```
  updateDB = (timestamp_key, item_name, item_url) => {
    firebase.database().ref(timestamp_key).set({
      item_name: item_name,
      item_url: item_url
    })
  }
```

I haven't been able to find a simple straightforward answer as to how to fetch one's device token and transmit that as well (so I know whose action is whose later).

Is there a (what I think should be) a relatively straightforward way to do that? Thanks!

P.S. I am calling this higher up in the script in addition to the configs to initialize the connection -- maybe it's somewhere around here I need to grab the device token?

```
// Initialize Firebase
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "blah",
  authDomain: "blah",
  databaseURL: "blah",
  storageBucket: "blah",
  messagingSenderId: "blah"
};

firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
```

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/client#access_the_registration_token

Comment: no good unfortunately -- get this error https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44308901/typeerror-firebase-messaging-is-not-a-function-in-node-js

Comment: how did you create your project?

Comment: @bennygenel could you elaborate on what you mean? I'm using Expo.

Comment: If you were created your project with react-native init I was gonna suggest to use some native library.

Answer (score 2):

So I'm using Expo with React Native as well. However, I'm using Google's Cloud Firestore instead of realtime database.

I'm not sure I understand your question completely, but this is how I am doing it:

```
const firebase = require('firebase');
import { Constants } from 'expo';

// Required for side-effects
require('firebase/firestore');
import { firebaseConfig } from './../keys';

class Fire {
  constructor() {
    this.init();
    this.observeAuth();
  }

  init = () => firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

  observeAuth = () => firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(this.onAuthStateChanged);

  onAuthStateChanged = user => {
    if (!user) {
      try {
        firebase.auth().signInAnonymously();
      } catch ({ message }) {
        console.warn(message);
      }
    } else {
      this.saveUser();
    }
  };

  saveUserInfo = () => {
    const { uid } = this;
    if (!uid) {
      return;
    }
    // You can add any information here
    const info = {
      deviceId: Constants.deviceId,
    };
    const ref = this.db.collection('users').doc(uid);
    const setWithMerge = ref.set({ uid, ...info }, { merge: true });
  };

  get db() {
    return firebase.firestore();
  }
  get uid() {
    return (firebase.auth().currentUser || {}).uid;
  }
}

Fire.shared = new Fire();
export default Fire;
```

I got most of this code from Evan Bacon's example - https://github.com/EvanBacon/Expo-Pillar-Valley.

Comment: what I ended up doing was following this example and doing `var DeviceID = Constants.deviceId;` and then transmitting the DeviceID up as a key.. it works for Expo, but wish there was a more universal answer.

Answer (score 0):

To use firebase in React Native you have to use native env.

Here is the steps:

**1. Eject your app**

```
npm run eject
```

or

```
yarn run eject
```

**2. Install React Native Firebase (RNFirebase)**

```
npm install --save react-native-firebase
```

or

```
yarn add react-native-firebase
```

**3. Setup following native**

You need to setup native app configuration for firebase app. Follow this step:

- [iOS Installation](https://rnfirebase.io/docs/v3.1.x/installation/ios)
- [Android Installation](https://rnfirebase.io/docs/v3.1.x/installation/android)

I am not gonna put step here since long step in there.

**4. Install dependency for database**

You have to setup dependency for native to use database libs. In the last step, you just setup the firebase core. Follow this step:

- [iOS Installation](https://rnfirebase.io/docs/v3.3.x/database/ios)
- [Android Installation](https://rnfirebase.io/docs/v3.1.x/database/android)

Again, I am not put here the step cause long story step.

**5. Usage**

This example usage for get options:

```
// get app id
firebase.app().options.appId

firebase.database().ref(path).set(val);


firebase.auth().signInAndRetrieveDataWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).then((response) => {
  console.log('signin with email', response);

  firebase.auth().currentUser.getToken().then((responseToken)=>{
    console.log('authorize', responseToken);
    this.setState({ authorize: responseToken });
  })
}).catch(function (err) {
  console.log('Unable to get sign in.', err);
});

if (Platform.OS === 'ios'){
  firebase.messaging().requestPermissions().then(() => {
    console.log('Notification permission granted.');
  }).catch((err) => {
    console.log('Unable to get permission to notify.', err);
  });
}
```

**6. Test your code**

Start your app by `react-native run-android` or `react-native run-ios` depends on your target.

Comment: i dont think this answers the question I'm looking for (unless I'm misunderstanding). Looks like you're doing authentication with Firebase, while I would just like to transmit the deviceID (or some equivalent unique ID key) up to the firebase database (as I am already sending up/logging `item_name` and `item_url`).